# Need Solution For Solving The Error

Tags: magento2, database, html, zend-framework

When I opening my site, I'm seeing an error. Screenshot of the error is attached.  Anybody can help please?[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Ubuntu**, please apply Below Solution
please run command:- **sudo service mysql status** and check MySQL status
if the status is inactive please run the command:- **sudo service mysql start** and again run status command and refresh your website page.

Comment: Thank you it's working.